# extract corrupted strings

Tags: r, string, corrupt-data

I received a file that had a weird encoding and wondered if there's any way to
check for 'corrupted' strings. For e.g.

```
dat <- c("å¤©è„Šç…¤åŒ–å·¥é›†å›¢è‚¡ä»½æœ‰é\231\220å…¬å\217¸", "AB \"\"Achema\"\"", 
         "Abu Qir Fertilizers & Chemical", "Abu Zaabal Fertilizer &", 
         "ADP - Adubos De Portugal SA")
```

The 1 and 2 element in above vector are corrupted since they have strings and escape characters in them. How can I filter these out or generate an index of corrupted strings in the vector `dat`

Comment: What is the output of `dat` you want ? or what the encoding of the file ?

Comment: The file was encoded in UTF-8. Irrespective of the encoding, the sample data is what it is. I simply want to extract strings that are all letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
error_string_idx <- which(
  is.na(
    iconv(
      dat,
      to = "ascii"
    ) 
  ) | grepl('\\\\|\\"', dat)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]" , "" , dat)
```

if you don't want empty character use

```
Filter(function(x) nchar(x) , gsub("[^a-zA-Z]" , "" , dat))
```